# Quick access to the previous search terms after calling isearch-forward without switching to the minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, isearch

I frequently re-search the terms previously searched by `isearch-forward` in my current session. 
Assume that I have searched `term1`, `term2`, ... during my previous I-searches. 
When I do a new `isearch-forward`, I would like to have a quick access to my previous search terms (say `term1`, `term2`, ... ), maybe to use them again. For this I have to switch to the minibuffer by putting the cursor in front of `I-search:` then pressing `Up-Arrow` `Down-Arrow` to have the access to the previous search terms, then pressing `RET` after selecting one of them.

Is there the possibility to do this without switching to the minibuffer? I mean pressing `Up-Arrow` `Down-Arrow` just after calling `isearch-forward` results in the access to previous search terms.

Comment: `C-h f isearch-forward` tells you everything you are asking about. And so does using `C-s` followed by `C-h`. **Ask Emacs**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `C-s C-s` you search the previous word. Then `M-p` (and `M-n`) for history.

Comment: This works when search is done using swiper package as well. Thanks